# Facebook in ruby, not rails!

Tags: ruby, rhomobile

I'm making a Cross-platform mobile app, with the fantastic framework "Rhodes".
But how am i getting people to connect through facebook..?

So what i wan't is, people should connect to facebook first in the application, and when they done that, it should sync with the facebook app(that app, are made). So i just want to make a connection with, facebook to Ruby. I tried with facebooker, but the I'd have to remove some stuff and then i din't know what to do..

Thank you in advance ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recently released [omniauth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem lets you build ruby web applications that utilize a variety of authentication providers including Facebook. Since it is a collection of Rack middleware you should be able to use it any Rack compatible Ruby framework.

Comment: so did you actually get this integrated with rhomobile?